# File not found by Python openai/whisper

Tags: openai-whisper

I've tried various arrangements of this file path name and an `ls` shows that the file is there. For simplicity, I'm in the directory as the file itself at the moment. I've stuck the print statement in `client.py` because that's where it's complaining:

```
>>> output = model.predict(audio="OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav")
 Kwargs: {}
 Kwargs: {'json': {'version': '770db50964b436879e870139c9c1504d6326774d8acc92e6815c19b68367ec51', 'input': {'audio': 'OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav'}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/replicate/model.py", line 20, in predict
    return latest_version.predict(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/replicate/version.py", line 18, in predict
    prediction = self._client.predictions.create(version=self, input=kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/replicate/prediction.py", line 72, in create
    json=body,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/replicate/client.py", line 55, in _request
    raise ReplicateError(resp.json()["detail"])
replicate.exceptions.ReplicateError: File does not exist: OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav
```

Same result from using `curl` too.

Comment: Does it work with absolute path to the file? Also, try getting python's working directory with `os.getcwd()` or listing files in cwd with `os.listdir()`. Does your python shell have access to the file? It may be permissions issue as well.

Comment: I'm hitting this too and so I wrapped the filename is `os.path.abspath(path)` and that wasn't it.  I'm wondering if the client code doesn't handle uploading the data to the server, and so it needs to be an URL?

Comment: I just checked the source, and it tests filenames with `isinstance(Path)`, so try passing `audio=pathlib.Path("OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav")` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi everyone, you are all right it's a 'path' not not an 'audio' so I think the doc is wrong. I'm currently trying to do this with `curl` and am now at: `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}` when they **** were! Probably go to Python later this morning.

Answer (score 0):

This is looking good:

```
import replicate
model = replicate.models.get("openai/whisper")
from pathlib import Path
audio_file = Path('/var/spool/mema/OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav')
output = model.predict(audio=audio_file)
```

Also on a Pi4 I had a lot of trouble with the replicate library. So I removed the pip installed one and installed from the repository.